# Checking line breaks (newline characters) with CFile

Tags: c++, mfc, newline, cfile

I need to check whether a file is ended with a line break or not, using `CFile`.
What I have tried:

1. point the file pointer at the end of the file
2. move the pointer back by 2 units
3. check if the pointer is pointing at `\r\n`

Here is my code:

```
cfile.SeekToEnd();
cfile.Seek(-2, CFile::current);
char buffer[2];
cfile.Read(buffer, 2);
if(buffer[0] == '\r' && buffer[1] == '\n') printf("Ended with line break!");
else printf("Not ended with line break!");
```

However, what I found is that the buffer gives me a `\n` character and a garbage character (with weird values like 204). After some research through the documentation, I found that [`CFile::Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctka0kks.aspx) only count `\r\n` as a single character:

> For text-mode files, carriage return–linefeed pairs are counted as single characters.

I am so confused because the file pointer obviously still counts 2 characters but I cannot get both of them. Is there any method to check line break at the end of a file with CFile?

Comment: We don't know, what type `cfile` is. Is it a `CFile` or something derived from it (like a `CStdioFile`)? As an aside, why aren't you simply calling `cfile.Seek(-2, CFile::end);` instead of the first two lines?

Comment: Oh, `cfile.Seek(-2, CFile::end);` is also a good idea. However I still get the same result. Btw, I am using `CFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `CFile::typeBinary` when opening a file.

It seems that `CFile::typeText` do something special processing carriage return–linefeed pairs (e.g. filling in a garbage character which is supposed to be a carriage return) which is not desired in my case.